# Add login hyperlink to secondary navigation menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, navigation, walker

I have the following lines of code in my **functions.php** file:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# Custom menu
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'top_nav' => 'Top Navigation Menu',
          'secondary_nav' => 'Secondary Navigation Menu <br /> <small>Will only display if applicable header layout is selected <a href="'. admin_url('?page=redux_options&tab=4') .'">here</a>.</small>'
        )
    );
}   


//dropdown arrows
class Theme_Arrow_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output) {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if (!empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) && $element->menu_item_parent == 0) { 
            $element->title =  $element->title . '<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span>'; 
            $element->classes[] = 'sf-with-ul';
        }

        if (!empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) && $element->menu_item_parent != 0) { 
            $element->title =  $element->title . '<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></span>'; 
        }

        Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
    }
}
```

And the following lines of code in my **header.php** file:

```
<?php if(has_nav_menu('secondary_nav')) { ?>
    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new Theme_Arrow_Walker_Nav_Menu, 'theme_location' => 'secondary_nav', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Which displays a primary and more importantly regarding this issue, a secondary navigation menu:

[image]

[image]

I would like to add a login navigation hyperlink, just below the *My Account* hyperlink, and remove it if the user is logged-in.

When adding this using the *Admin* > *Appearance* > *Menus* settings...

[image]

It leaves the login navigation hyperlink there, even if the user is logged-in.

How would I be able to add a login navigation hyperlink to my secondary navigation menu, and remove it from the list once the user is logged in to the website, and if possible without an additional plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a filter on `wp_get_nav_menu_items`.

In this example, we first check if it's the admin screen or the user is not logged in, and bail out if that's the case.

Then we look at each menu item and find the one with `Log In` as the menu item title, and unset it.

```
function wpa_remove_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if( is_admin() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $items;

    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( 'Log In' == $item->title ) unset( $items[$key] );
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa_remove_menu_item', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi there Milo.  I'm not too sure if I've done something wrong, but this doesn't seem to add a Log In hyperlink just below the My Account hyperlink.  I basically need a Log In hyperlink to appear when the user is not logged in, and for it to then be removed when they are.

Comment: This doesn't add menu items, it *removes* an item you've added to the menu.

Comment: Yes, I understand this.  `I would like to add a login navigation hyperlink, just below the My Account hyperlink, and remove it if the user is logged-in.`

Comment: Go to appearance > menus and under Links, add a link to the login page.

Comment: Ahhhh...Gotcha Milo. It must be frustrating working with people like me.